# Default value in DropDown of IceFaces

Tags: jsf, default-value

I have a jspx page with code:

```
<ice:outputText id="regionTitle" value="#{msg['tc.report.region']} *"/>
<ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:panelGrid  columns="2" 
                    columnClasses="column90, column10" 
                    width="100%">
        <ice:selectInputText id="regionInput" 
                             binding="#{frm_4_20Bean.regionInput}" 
                             width="100%" 
                             value="#{frm_4_20Bean.regionSI.selectedItemKey}" 
                             valueChangeListener="#{frm_4_20Bean.regionSI.itemCodeValueChanged}">
            <f:selectItems id="regionList" 
                           value="#{frm_4_20Bean.regionSI.codeItems}" />
        </ice:selectInputText>
        <ice:commandLink actionListener="#{frm_4_20Bean.regionController.openPopup}" 
                         onclick="hideAllSelectsIE6();">
            <ice:graphicImage   value="/img/open.gif" 
                                alt="show popup" 
                                style="border:none"/>
        </ice:commandLink>
    </ice:panelGrid>
</ice:panelGroup>
```

And I want to know, how to set default value for `<ice:selectInputText />`. Please show me some example code.

Comment: Just instantiate the `regionInput` binding to a value: `regionInput.setValue("The default")`.

Comment: @kolossus, in constructor, I set the value like: `regionInput.setValue("6201");` and after executing that code, app throws NullPointerException. But when I wrote it in button click listener, it works perfectly. What might be wrong?

Comment: @BalusC, your method is working. Put your comment like a answer.